# Add function parameter to SQL query WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, functions, java, dynamic-sql

I have a web application in java and it uses a query. I don't want to write the query into Java, so I made a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFunc(inputs text) RETURNS TABLE(...) AS 
$$
    SELECT .... FROM ...
    JOIN ...
    where true
    ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I want the Function parameter INPUTS to also be in the WHERE clause so if inputs is

```
AND speed = 0 AND ....
```

Where clause looks like

```
where true AND speed = 0 AND ...
```

How can i achieve this?

**EDIT**

Also it is acceptable to have many parameters (a int, b string, c string ..) but then i need to have

```
WHERE speed = * AND stop = * AND ...
```

which is not acceptable. How can i achieve this ?

OR can i put a if statement inside it ? Like

```
Select .. . from ...
JOIN ... 
WHERE true
IF (a != null){AND speed = $1}
IF ....
;
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Instead I made a view and now I'm callingit it `SELECT * FROM myView WHERE speed = 4`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't always pass *all* parameters, create a function with **parameter defaults**. The basic, simple form would be an SQL function without dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func(_a int  = NULL
                              , _b text = NULL
                              , _c text = NULL)
  RETURNS TABLE(...) AS
$func$
    SELECT ... FROM ...
    WHERE (speed = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)
    AND   (stop  = $2 OR $2 IS NULL)
    ...
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Now you can call the function with any number of parameters using named notation:

```
SELECT * FROM func(_c => 'foo', _a => 123);  -- no _b, which defaults to NULL
```

Note, the [assignment operator in the call is **`=>`** (or `:=` for Postgres 9.4 or older)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001209/939860), *not* `=`!
See:

- [The forgotten assignment operator “=” and the commonplace “:=”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001209/939860)
- [Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789179/939860)

Aside: "string" is not a data type, `text` is.

Much more is possible with **dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a plpgsql function**.

More comprehensive answer on SO with complete recipes:

- [Test for is null or = value in function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355733/939860)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dynamic queries. Here is a page about it. Check out about 2/3rds of the way down after "Example 40-1. Quoting Values In Dynamic Queries". But like it states, you need to be VERY careful. Doing this type of SQL creation on the fly can be a huge hole for SQL injection.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html