# SELECT optimization in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I want to select last unique rows based on time, so:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (track) *
 FROM   eco.tracks WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM eco.tracks WHERE time_track < ((SELECT time_track FROM eco.tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)  - INTERVAL '300 seconds')  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
 ORDER  BY track, time_track DESC;
```

It takes 20 seconds, that's too slow.
If I replace `id` by the actual value, the query takes only 2 ms:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (track) *
FROM   eco.tracks WHERE id > 48000000
ORDER  BY track, time_track DESC;
```

That subquery alone takes only 2 ms.

```
SELECT id FROM eco.tracks
WHERE  time_track < ((SELECT time_track FROM eco.tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) - INTERVAL '300 seconds')
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Why the big difference?

Comment: Please consider instructions here for Postgres performance questions: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball says the two queries end up using different query plans. You can verify by running `EXPLAIN` on each. More useful details with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

The subquery gets the greatest `id` with `time_track` more than 5 minutes before the one of the greatest `id` overall in table `eco.tracks`. Assuming a strong positive correlation between `id` and `time_track`, humans get a rough idea of the work to be done here: it only concerns the (probably very few) latest rows within the last 5 minutes in the table. But **Postgres has no idea at the time of planning the query**.

(Aside: It *may* be a lingering logic bug to assume that serial IDs are in sync with timestamps in the column `time_track`. Not enough information to say more.)

For the **first (slow) query**, Postgres *has to* prepare a plan that best copes with *any* value that might come out of the subquery. That may very well be a sequential scan, which turns out to be a bad choice for only the few latest rows.

For the **second (fast) query**, Postgres *knows* from the given value what to expect. It can start by identifying the few relevant rows with an index or bitmap index scan on an index on `(id)` which undoubtably exists (again *assuming* that's the PK). The rest is peanuts.

### Possible solutions

There are many ways. Anything to get Postgres to pick the appropriate query plan ...

#### 1. Two separate queries

Dead simple. Build the second query with the actual value returned from the first. The **downside**: two round trips to the db server collecting two times network latency and varying overhead.

#### 2. Dynamic SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_latest_tracks(_intv interval = '300 seconds')
  RETURNS SETOF eco.tracks AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
'SELECT DISTINCT ON (track) *
 FROM   eco.tracks
 WHERE  id > $1
 ORDER  BY track, time_track DESC'
USING (
   SELECT id
   FROM   eco.tracks
   WHERE  time_track < (SELECT time_track - _intv FROM eco.tracks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
   ORDER  BY id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   );

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_latest_tracks();
SELECT * FROM f_latest_tracks('10 minutes');
```

Why? [The manual about ***Executing Dynamic Commands***:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> The important difference is that `EXECUTE` will re-plan the command on
>   each execution, generating a plan that is specific to the current
>   parameter values; whereas PL/pgSQL may otherwise create a generic plan
>   and cache it for re-use. In situations where the best plan depends
>   strongly on the parameter values, it can be helpful to use `EXECUTE` to
>   positively ensure that a generic plan is not selected.

Downside: You need to create a server-side function introducing a dependency on  table `eco.tracks`. And you need to be comfortable with PL/pgSQL, of course.

Using a parameter default for conveniencse. See:

- [Add function parameter to SQL query WHERE clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/85970/add-function-parameter-to-sql-query-where-clause/85976#85976)

Comment: Jzs! Just brilliant answer! Can u suggest some manuals/courses/books for PostgreSQL?!
Thank you so much!

Comment: I keep suggesting [*the* manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/): It's authoritative and mostly excellent. Enormous, though.